# how to change inner values of attribute of html element using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have following HTML

```
<div class="badgeSignUp" value="{'component':'LP-Popup', 'flowType':'f', 'category': 'SM-Flight-HP', 'campaignId' : '5'}">
```

I want to change value of "category" using jquery.

How to do this in best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adjusting `html` to set `value` attribute within single quotes `''`, set properties of `value` within in double quotes `""`

```
<div class="badgeSignUp" value='{"component":"LP-Popup", "flowType":"f", "category": "SM-Flight-HP", "campaignId" : "5"}'>
```

utilize [`.attr(function(attributeName, function))`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) to parse, set value of `category` property of `attr` , return `attr` set at `.badgeSignUp`

```js
$(".badgeSignUp").attr("value", function(i, value) {
  var data = JSON.parse(value);
  // set `category` property of `data`
  data.category = "abc123";
  console.log(data);
  return JSON.stringify(data);
});

console.log($(".badgeSignUp").attr("value"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="badgeSignUp" value='{"component":"LP-Popup", "flowType":"f", "category": "SM-Flight-HP", "campaignId" : "5"}'></div>
```

---

> can't change html

```js
$(".badgeSignUp").attr("value", function(i, value) {
  return value.replace(/('category': 'SM-Flight-HP')/, "'category': 'abc123'")
});

console.log($(".badgeSignUp").attr("value"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="badgeSignUp" value="{'component':'LP-Popup', 'flowType':'f', 'category': 'SM-Flight-HP', 'campaignId' : '5'}"></div>
```

Comment: that's fine I can change quotes but what if I can't change html let's say it's an interview question